# Proving increasing iota in Coq

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

I am stuck on a goal.

Assume we have the following definition:

```
Fixpoint iota (n : nat) : list nat :=
  match n with
    | 0   => []
    | S k => iota k ++ [k]
  end.
```

And we want to prove:

`Theorem t1 : forall n, In n (iota n) -> False.`

So far, I have managed to the following:

```
Theorem t1 : forall n, In n (iota n) -> False.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction n.
    - cbn in H. contradiction.
    - cbn in H. apply app_split in H.
      Focus 2. unfold not. intros.
      unfold In in H0. destruct H0. assert (~(n = S n)) by now apply s_inj.
      contradiction.
      apply H0.
      apply IHn.
```

I used these two lemmas, proofs omitted:

```
Axiom app_split : forall A x (l l2 : list A), In x (l ++ l2) -> not (In x l2) -> In x l.
Axiom s_inj     : forall n, ~(n = S n).
```

However, I am completely stuck, I need to somehow show that: `In n (iota n)` assuming `In (S n) (iota n)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've observed the fact that the `n` in `In n` and the one in `iota n` are in lockstep in your statement makes the induction hypothesis hard to invoke (if not completely useless).

The trick here is to prove a more general statement than the one you are actually interested in which breaks this dependency between the two `n`s. I would suggest:

```
Theorem t : forall n k, n <= k -> In k (iota n) -> False.
```

from which you can derive `t1` as a corollary:

```
Corollary t1 : forall n, In n (iota n) -> False.
intro n; apply (t n n); reflexivity.
Qed.
```

If you want to peek at the proof of `t`, you can [have a look at this self-contained gist](https://gist.github.com/gallais/83e84596e08b15dfa605b2d7c696f734)

Comment: Interesting - how does one get the intuition for when something's impossible to prove with its current formulation - is it that either some of the assumptions or the inductive hypothesis would be directly (or indirectly) in contradiction with the conclusion? Or is there a notion of "not sufficient / strong" enough inductive hypothesis? How can one tell? (This is obvious once you show me, but figuring this out myself...)

Comment: Experience mostly. But whenever two things are in lockstep or one value is fixed to be a constant and that prevents you from using the induction hypothesis, that's a strong smell that you may want to look for a more general statement. [This blog post](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~jrw12/InductionExercises.html) sets up a number of exercises where you have to generalize the induction hypothesis to make it work. You may want to look into it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Basically I need to "git gud" :).